# Adding foreign key to form

Tags: python, django, web

I have this model:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    thread = models.ForeignKey(Thread)
    post_title = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    # other attributes
```

And I have a view:

```
class ThreadView(CreateView):
    model = models.Post
    template_name = 'forum/thread.html'
    fields = ['post_title', 'author', 'post_text']
```

When I try to send the form I get IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: forum_post.thread_id.
I think, it's because I foreign key remains empty, but I don't know how to add it automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the name of the view you have is not quiet obvious, cause you are trying to create an instance of a Post not of a Thread. Won't it be better to rename it to PostCreateView?

Speaking about the error you get, you are right about foreign key - it is empty. After all, you do not set it anywhere. You should either send it in the form or assign it on validation. The second way is what you are looking for:

```
class ThreadView(CreateView):
    model = models.Post
    template_name = 'forum/thread.html'
    fields = ['post_title', 'author', 'post_text']

    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.thread = get_object_or_404(Thread, pk=kwargs['thread_id'])
        return super(ThreadView, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)

    def form_valid(self, form):
            form.instance.thread = self.thread
            return super(ThreadView, self).form_valid(form)
```

Comment: Thank you, this is what I need.

Answer (score 0):

I think you must add ForeginKey Feild into Views Feilds

```
fields = ['thread', 'post_title', 'author', 'post_text']
```

and be sure there is a data in `thread` model

Comment: This way let me choose some thread, but I need to django do it automatically.

Comment: according to what you need to choose ?

Comment: According the thread, in which I'm adding a post. id of current thread I get from url: url(r'^thread/(?P<t_id>[0-9]+)/$', ...)

Comment: you need to choose `thread` according to `post`  when you select the post 
return the thread ?

Comment: Yes. I go to url "mysite/.../thread/1" and get list of post of thread number 1. I want to put this id to the form programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your view:

```
def post(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.t_id = kwargs["t_id"]
    return super(ThreadView, self).post(*args, **kwargs)

def form_valid(self, form):
    self.object = form.save(commit=False)
    self.object.thread = Thread.objects.get(pk=self.t_id)
    form.save_m2m()
    return super(ModelFormMixin, self).form_valid(form)
```

Comment: 'PostForm' object has no attribute 'save_m2m'

Comment: Edited. Does this fix the problem?

Comment: No, I think post is executed after form_valid.

Comment: Edited. Does this fix the problem? I set `self.t_id` before calling `super`.